# How to use git command(s) to show commits modifying any of a large list of (>10K) files?

Tags: git

I have a large list of (>10K) files that a project module depends on, I have all the paths listed in a text file file-list.txt:

```
path/to/file1
path/to/file2
...
```

How can I get the git commits that modify any of these files?

Comment: Is it usually "all files under a handful of directories"?

Comment: Have you verified that it's more files than `xargs` can pass to the command in a single invokation?

Comment: just do  a script which find intersection between you paths and the result of the `git log --name-only` or a similar  command.

Comment: So I tried `git log "$(< file-list.txt)"` and got the `Argument list too long` error. I'll try to write a script to get the intersection of file paths.
The files are under hundreds of directories.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` the manifest file to `git log`

Example:

```
$ fd -t f | sed 5q | xargs git log --oneline --stat
```

```
4a7701e improve func
 asm/args_libc.asm | 32 +++++++++++++++++---------------
 1 file changed, 17 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)
79c2e94 byte convention
 arduino/stepper_motor.ino | 12 ++++++------
 1 file changed, 6 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
a486363 stepper motor
 arduino/stepper_motor.ino | 39 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------
 1 file changed, 28 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)
f5c4746 stepper motor finished
 arduino/stepper_motor.ino | 38 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 38 insertions(+)
659bb6e arg table
 asm/args_libc.asm | 27 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 27 insertions(+)
5a70e9b effective addressing
 asm/args.asm | 34 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------
 1 file changed, 26 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
4a64f50 asm print argc
 asm/args.asm | 28 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 28 insertions(+)
ee67898 IN temp OUT led
 arduino/temp_led.ino | 31 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 31 insertions(+)
cfe4618 print ascii table
 asm/ascii/Makefile | 11 +++++++++++
 1 file changed, 11 insertions(+)
```

if there's overlap in the commits, just sort/uniq it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starter kit:

```
git log --all --reflog --pretty=format:%H --name-status \
| awk -F$'\t' '
        ARGIND==1 { files[$0]=1; next }   /* load up the list of files first */
        NF==1     { commit=$1; next }     /* single-field line is commit id */
        $2 in files && commit!=printed { print printed=commit }
    '  file-list.txt -
```

pipe the results through e.g. `git log --stdin --no-walk --name-status --oneline` to annotate it for checking.